# I need a team-building algorithm that takes restrictions into account

Tags: algorithm, optimization, constraints

my scenario is the following:

We have a certain set of Positions which need to be filled each by a person. But a Position requires specific skills. So let a Position be [ ] and we have different skills like A,B,C,D. Now the Position [A,C] needs a Person that has the skills A and C.
We have a pool of Persons to choose from. Each Person has a different set of skills and is on a different Location. But we want the physically closest Person that also has the required skills to get the Position.

What would be a way to find the optimal Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to solve a typical [Maximum weight matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum-weight_matching).

Create nodes for each Position, they will be the first part of graph. Create nodes for each Person, they will be the second part of graph. Add edges from each position [A, B] to all persons that have both skills A and B.

Define a weigth of edge from position to person as something that is as big as person and position locations are close to each other - for example, `1 / distance(person, position)`, or `some_constant - distance(person, position)`.

Then you can use any algorithm that solves mentioned problem and you'll have your matching.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Let's say i want to use the Hungarian_algorithm to solve my problem and i want to use a Matrix interpretation of this algorithm instead of a bipartite graph because a matrix would be better inside the framework i am working with. Would this be possible? Because some fields of the Matrix are empty. Like Person X and Position [ A ] if Person X doesn't have the skill A. The examples i found had the assumptions that everyone can have any position.

Comment: In matrix formulation you'll look for a matching with minimum cost, so `matrix[i][j]` will be a distance between position i and person j. If person does not match this position, you can set `matrix[i][j] = some_very_big_constant`, for example, `2^16`. (Keep in mind that you may overflow your numeric type if you make this constant too big, `2^16` should be optimal for 32-bit numbers). This way the algorithm will always try not to add this edge to an answer, but if it won't have any better choice, it will add it, so you'll need to remove these edges from an answer.